# How do I Exclude RSS feeds from Fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

I'm completely new to Fiddler (installed in yesterday) and in my Web Sessions section all of my RSS feeds in my bookmarks are being captured. Is there a way to stop Fiddler from doing that so I can just watch the request made for what I'm currently working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using regular expressions for the filters. In the 'Filters' tab you have to choose 'Show only if the URL contains'.

If you put a regex string in there that allows everything except RSS feeds those will be filtered:

```
REGEX:(?insx).*[^(rss2|rss|rdf)]$
```

You can add of course more filetypes to the list, if required.